# Pressure to Images and Images to pressure conversion

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, bioinformatics, yolo

EDIT:I am working on the Pressure map dataset where the pressure sensors data is "in-bed posture pressure data".

Dataset : https://physionet.org/content/pmd/1.0.0/

Using the below code I could able to convert the pressure data to images.

```
line = f.readlines()[3]
lst1 = line.strip().split()
lst = [int(x) for x in lst1]

# Convert into a 64*32 array
rr = np.asarray(lst).reshape(64, 32)

plt.imshow(arr, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
```

Images formed are as below:

[image]

Now, my major motto is to analyze each body part individually. For that, I am taking the bounding boxes for body parts and then I need to get the original sensor data in that part and then analyse using the pressure values.

Let say I am analysing the head part. For that, I have to get the original pressure data of that sub-portion. Sub-portion is decided by the bounding boxes using the images.

How can I get the original pressure values using the bounding boxes of images?

Comment: I am unclear as to what your question is. You seem to say in the last sentence what you can't do, but in the previous sentence you seem to say that same thing is straightforward?

Comment: Made little changes to the question.

Comment: Problem is - I am able to generate the images from the pressure dataset. Then I need to fetch the sub-portion of pressure data, by identifying the coordinates of the body part (let say head). Using image I can get the bounding box. But with bounding box how can I get the pressure which was used to generate the image.

Comment: They are still in your array `arr[]` surely?

Comment: Yes. I have the original data still in the array.

Comment: So if your bounding box is rows 10..20, columns 80..90, you can get that ROI (Region of Interest) with `ROI = arr[10:20,80:90]`

Comment: But I am a little confused here. If I see the image shape it is (220, 112, 3). Are you sure, the direct mapping will help without any error? I would like to understand how this mapping happens.

Comment: Oh, I see it is 3-colour RGB, so you need `ROI=arr[10:20,80:90,:]` to get all 3 channels.

Comment: No, assume, 10:20,80:90 is the position of the head. Then, I have pressure array in the shape 64*32. Which part of this array is contributing to the head? If you observe, image dimensions are much greater than the pressure array dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments I think you used the output image to determine the position of the head. However the output image is scaled up, meaning more pixels then the amount of data points. That is why your range is outside of the array dimensions.

Here is an image where each data point is 1 pixel (hard to see, in gray values):

[image]

I plotted the same image using your code:

[image]

Notice how you can count the actual data points as blocks of color. The axis equal data point count in column/row. I had the mouse on the head position, so it's (rounded) location is at x=13, y=3.

Then, selection of the general head area:

```
head = arr[1:7,10:18]
print(head)
plt.imshow(head, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
```

Gives values:

> [[ 49  54  99 182 214 106  33  35]
>    [ 22  49 229 257 314 224  81   5]
>    [ 15  55 131 194 177 199  59   5]
>    [  7  20  61  96 144 346  19   3]
>    [  2   3  19  33  60  83  10   0]
>    [  9   5  11  13  72  46   2   0]]

[image]

It may be a little hard to see, because the colors are remapped.